# How is the atomic unlock-and-block achieved in the implementation of synchronization primitives like mutexes and condition variables?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, atomic

For example, suppose you are using atomic spinlock on an integer flag to ensure only one thread modifies the wait-queue that the mutex maintains at any given time. When a thread tries to lock the mutex, we want it to enqueue itself and set the flag to zero before it blocks itself and the unlocker to dequeue a thread from the queue and set it to runnable.

Consider only two threads to be present, one locking and the other releasing the mutex at the same time. if the locker was preempted after it added himself to the queue and set the flag to zero (but not blocked itself yet) and the unlocker then tried to dequeue and make the thread runnable, it wouldn't be useful since the thread hasn't blocked itself yet. So the make-runnable call would be waste but more importantly, the locker thread would then block itself after that and would remain blocked forever.

How is this atomicity achieved to ensure correctness? A similar scenario can be imagined in condition variables with the release of mutex and blocking itself.